# facing this error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression whats my mistake?

Tags: sql

Here is my SQL query:

```
select f_name, avg(age) 
from students 
group by dept_id 
having avg(age) > age;
```

Why does this result in an error I mentioned in the question title?

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and the results you want.

Comment: Your f_name is not in `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `GROUP BY` a column if it is included in the `SELECT` statement. Also, if you're using a `GROUP BY` clause, you need to include all non-aggregate function columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Try:

```
select f_name, avg(age), dept_id
from students 
group by f_name, dept_id 
--not sure about this next line either
--having avg(age) > age;
```

Answer (score 0):

f_name is not an aggregate on the group by. Try for instance min(f_name).

not sure if "having avg(age) > age;" will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have `f_name` in the `select`, but are aggregating by department.

Your having clause mixes aggregations and non-aggregations.

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, avg(s.age) over (partition by s.dept_id) as avg_age
      from students s
     ) s 
where s.age > avg_age;
```